# JSON post to the elastic API using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, ssis, script-task

I have an elastic post API. To fetch the data from the post API I am using the below JSON code in the body section in postman.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "platform": {
              "query": "COSMOS"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "cu_ticketLastUpdated_date": {
              "gte": "2022-05-30 00:00:00",
              "lt": "2022-05-31 23:59:59"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the JSON data which is getting post execution of above filters in the body section in postman

```json
{
    "took": 513,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 42,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 3.2640164,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "piqreporting",
                "_type": "ticketData",
                "_id": "9845628",
                "_score": 3.2640164,
                "_source": {
                    "claimNumber": "1234556",
                    "adjustmentNumber": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "claimICN": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "claimStatus": "A",
                    "claimType": "I",
                    "claimFirstDateService": "2020-06-02",
                    "claimLastDateService": "2020-06-03",
                    "isBehaviourHealth": "false",
                    "claimPatientAccountNumber": "52088867500",
                    "claimBillingAmount": "6287.91",
                    "claimPaidAmount": "2579.66",
                    "claimCAE": "COSMOS",
                    "subscriberId": "943634985",
                    "memberId": "943634985",
                    "subscriberFirstName": "CLAYTON",
                    "subscriberLastName": "CASH",
                    "subscriberDateOfBirth": "1969-01-06",
                    "subscriberAddress": "163 BLAKE ST APT 1 ",
                    "patientFirstName": "CLAYTON",
                    "patientLastName": "CASH",
                    "patientMiddleName": "A",
                    "patientDateOfBirth": "1969-01-06",
                    "govProgramCode": "2",
                    "coverageStartDate": "2020-04-01",
                    "coverageEndDate": "2020-12-31",
                    "relationshipCode": "EE",
                    "divisionCode": "NYC",
                    "sourceId": "NYC6610094363498500",
                    "billingMpin": "000568859",
                    "billingProviderName": "Yale New Haven Hospital",
                    "renderingMpin": "003928974",
                    "ticketNumber": "9845628",
                    "tpsmCode": "S",
                    "ticketTpsmIndicator": "134",
                    "ticketTpsmEffectiveDate": "2017-06-01",
                    "ticketSubmissionDate": "2022-05-30",
                    "ticketSubmitterName": "Durga Singidi",
                    "ticketType": "Recon",
                    "ticketQueue": "Cosmos Inst SAS MnR",
                    "providerTin": "060646652",
                    "policyNumber": "66100",
                    "sharedAmount": "00",
                    "ticketStatus": "Under Review",
                    "ticketSubmitterEmail": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "ticketSubmitterPhone": "1234567890",
                    "amountOwned": "878.00",
                    "amountOwnedFlag": "N",
                    "ticketLastUpdated": "2022-05-30",
                    "ticketLastUpdatedBy": "System",
                    "claimSubmissionTransactionId": "N/A",
                    "sourceApplication": "SDE",
                    "serviceProviderLastName": "Yale New Haven Hospital",
                    "productId": "00526",
                    "depedentSequenceNumber": "00",
                    "stateOfIssue": "CT",
                    "subscriberAddressLine1": "163 BLAKE ST APT 1",
                    "subscriberCity": "NEW HAVEN",
                    "subscriberState": "CT",
                    "subscriberZip5": "06515",
                    "billingType": "131",
                    "claimIndicator": "I",
                    "claimRecievedDate": "2020-06-08",
                    "ticketLastUpdatedName": "System",
                    "ticketTpsmCancelDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "planBenefitTypeCode": "MD",
                    "claimNetworkStatus": "I",
                    "offshoreRestricted": "N",
                    "isEmployeeRestricted": "N",
                    "providerComments": "Integration testing with PIQ for COSMOS",
                    "platform": "COSMOS",
                    "payerId": "87726",
                    "payerName": "UnitedHealthcare",
                    "kafkaWorkflow": "COMPLETED",
                    "resubmissionCount": "0",
                    "assignedTopic": "STOP",
                    "cu_ticketSubmittedDate_date": "2022-05-30 09:58:33",
                    "cu_ticketLastUpdated_date": "2022-05-30 09:59:34.057",
                    "cu_ticketNumber": "PIQ-9845628",
                    "cu_totalAttachments_int": 0,
                    "cu_resubmission_count_int": 0,
                    "cu_bizAge_int": 1,
                    "actualClaimNumber": "NYC094995559",
                    "coverageType": "M",
                    "remarkCodes": "0208",
                    "advocateCreatedOn": "2022-05-30",
                    "ticketAdjustment": [
                        {
                            "adjustmentNumber": "XXXXXXXXX",
                            "adjustmentSource": "COSMOS",
                            "createdOn": "2022-05-30"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ticketResubmissions": [
                        {
                            "openDate": "2022-05-30"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ticketComments": [
                        {
                            "comment": "Integration testing with PIQ for COSMOS",
                            "category": "External",
                            "createdBy": "Durga Singidi",
                            "createDate": "2022-05-30",
                            "reconRequestReason": "Reimbursement or Medical Policy Decision"
                        },
                        {
                            "comment": "Under Review",
                            "category": "Internal",
                            "createdBy": "System",
                            "ticketStatus": "Under Review",
                            "createDate": "2022-05-30",
                            "conclusion": "Under Review",
                            "reconRequestReason": "Reimbursement or Medical Policy Decision",
                            "createdById": "System"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "piqreporting",
                "_type": "ticketData",
                "_id": "9845624",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "claimNumber": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "adjustmentNumber": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "claimICN": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "claimStatus": "A",
                    "claimType": "P",
                    "claimFirstDateService": "2021-07-03",
                    "claimLastDateService": "2021-07-03",
                    "isBehaviourHealth": "false",
                    "claimPatientAccountNumber": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "claimBillingAmount": "1330.00",
                    "claimPaidAmount": "63.97",
                    "claimCAE": "FACETS - CSP",
                    "subscriberId": "121586082",
                    "memberId": "121586082",
                    "subscriberFirstName": "STEPHEN",
                    "subscriberLastName": "BOLDIN",
                    "subscriberDateOfBirth": "1965-02-24",
                    "subscriberAddress": "2137 N. BELL AVENUE ",
                    "patientFirstName": "STEPHEN",
                    "patientLastName": "BOLDIN",
                    "patientMiddleName": "W",
                    "patientDateOfBirth": "1965-02-24",
                    "govProgramCode": "3",
                    "coverageStartDate": "2021-07-01",
                    "coverageEndDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "groupNumber": "AZMC",
                    "relationshipCode": "EE",
                    "sourceId": "AZMCARE 12158608201",
                    "billingMpin": "000121184",
                    "billingProviderName": "Tucson Medical Center",
                    "renderingMpin": "000121184",
                    "renderingProviderName": "NADER MAKKI",
                    "ticketNumber": "9845624",
                    "tpsmCode": "S",
                    "ticketTpsmIndicator": "424",
                    "ticketTpsmEffectiveDate": "2017-12-20",
                    "ticketSubmissionDate": "2022-05-30",
                    "ticketSubmitterName": "Durga Singidi",
                    "ticketType": "Recon",
                    "ticketQueue": "Facets  CSP",
                    "providerTin": "860137567",
                    "policyNumber": "AZMCARE",
                    "ticketStatus": "Under Review",
                    "ticketSubmitterEmail": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "ticketSubmitterPhone": "1234567890",
                    "amountOwned": "676.00",
                    "amountOwnedFlag": "N",
                    "ticketLastUpdated": "2022-05-30",
                    "ticketLastUpdatedBy": "System",
                    "claimSubmissionTransactionId": "N/A",
                    "sourceApplication": "SDE",
                    "serviceProviderLastName": "Tucson Medical Center",
                    "productId": "AZMCARE",
                    "depedentSequenceNumber": "01",
                    "stateOfIssue": "AZ",
                    "subscriberAddressLine1": "2137 N. BELL AVENUE",
                    "subscriberCity": "TUCSON",
                    "subscriberState": "AZ",
                    "subscriberZip5": "857120000",
                    "claimIndicator": "I",
                    "claimRecievedDate": "2021-07-23",
                    "ticketLastUpdatedName": "System",
                    "ticketTpsmCancelDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "planBenefitTypeCode": "MD",
                    "claimNetworkStatus": "I",
                    "offshoreRestricted": "N",
                    "isEmployeeRestricted": "N",
                    "providerComments": "Integration testing with PIQ",
                    "platform": "FACETS - CSP",
                    "payerId": "87726",
                    "payerName": "UnitedHealthcare",
                    "kafkaWorkflow": "COMPLETED",
                    "providerRequestReason": "Patient Eligibility",
                    "resubmissionCount": "0",
                    "assignedTopic": "STOP",
                    "cu_ticketSubmittedDate_date": "2022-05-30 09:41:05",
                    "cu_ticketLastUpdated_date": "2022-05-30 09:42:54.394",
                    "cu_ticketNumber": "PIQ-9845624",
                    "cu_totalAttachments_int": 0,
                    "cu_resubmission_count_int": 0,
                    "cu_bizAge_int": 1,
                    "actualClaimNumber": "21H991583800",
                    "coverageType": "M",
                    "facetsprovIdBilling": "0808709004",
                    "facetsprovIdRendering": "6817639003",
                    "remarkCodes": "PXN",
                    "advocateCreatedOn": "2022-05-30",
                    "ticketAdjustment": [
                        {
                            "adjustmentNumber": "SF20220530824490967",
                            "adjustmentSource": "FACETS - CSP",
                            "createdOn": "2022-05-30"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ticketResubmissions": [
                        {
                            "openDate": "2022-05-30"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ticketComments": [
                        {
                            "comment": "Integration testing with PIQ",
                            "category": "External",
                            "createdBy": "Durga Singidi",
                            "createDate": "2022-05-30",
                            "reconRequestReason": "Patient Eligibility"
                        },
                        {
                            "comment": "Under Review",
                            "category": "Internal",
                            "createdBy": "System",
                            "ticketStatus": "Under Review",
                            "createDate": "2022-05-30",
                            "conclusion": "Under Review",
                            "reconRequestReason": "Patient Eligibility",
                            "createdById": "System"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "piqreporting",
                "_type": "ticketData",
                "_id": "9845631",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "claimNumber": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "claimICN": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "claimStatus": "01",
                    "claimType": "I",
                    "claimFirstDateService": "2021-11-14",
                    "claimLastDateService": "2021-11-14",
                    "isBehaviourHealth": "false",
                    "claimPatientAccountNumber": "53010242800",
                    "claimBillingAmount": "737.88",
                    "claimPaidAmount": "369.98",
                    "claimCAE": "CIRRUS",
                    "subscriberId": "720845839",
                    "memberId": "72084583900",
                    "subscriberFirstName": "RACHEL",
                    "subscriberLastName": "PERDO",
                    "subscriberDateOfBirth": "1987-10-18",
                    "subscriberAddress": "330 SHORT BEACH ROAD APARTMENT I 12",
                    "patientFirstName": "RACHEL",
                    "patientLastName": "PERDO",
                    "patientDateOfBirth": "1987-10-18",
                    "coverageStartDate": "2021-09-01",
                    "coverageEndDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "groupNumber": "1273808",
                    "relationshipCode": "EE",
                    "sourceId": "72084583900",
                    "billingMpin": "000568859",
                    "billingProviderName": "Yale New Haven Hospital",
                    "renderingMpin": "005231819",
                    "ticketNumber": "9845631",
                    "tpsmCode": "S",
                    "ticketTpsmIndicator": "134",
                    "ticketTpsmDescription": "STRATEGIC_NE_YALE LAWRENCE & MEMORIAL",
                    "ticketTpsmEffectiveDate": "2017-06-01",
                    "ticketSubmissionDate": "2022-05-30",
                    "ticketSubmitterName": "Shrutika Kadam",
                    "ticketType": "Recon",
                    "ticketQueue": "Cirrus Triage General",
                    "providerTin": "060646652",
                    "policyNumber": "1273808",
                    "ticketStatus": "New",
                    "ticketSubmitterEmail": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "ticketSubmitterPhone": "9876543210",
                    "amountOwned": "990.00",
                    "amountOwnedFlag": "N",
                    "ticketLastUpdated": "2022-05-30",
                    "ticketLastUpdatedBy": "System",
                    "claimSubmissionTransactionId": "N/A",
                    "sourceApplication": "SDE",
                    "serviceProviderFirstName": "Pirjo",
                    "serviceProviderLastName": "Aalto Fischer",
                    "productId": "PM00000013",
                    "stateOfIssue": "CT",
                    "subscriberAddressLine1": "330 SHORT BEACH ROAD",
                    "subscriberAddressLine2": "APARTMENT I 12",
                    "subscriberCity": "EAST HAVEN",
                    "subscriberState": "CT",
                    "subscriberZip5": "06512",
                    "billingType": "131",
                    "claimIndicator": "I",
                    "claimRecievedDate": "2021-12-03",
                    "ticketLastUpdatedName": "System",
                    "ticketTpsmCancelDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "claimNetworkStatus": "I",
                    "offshoreRestricted": "N",
                    "isEmployeeRestricted": "N",
                    "providerComments": "test",
                    "platform": "CIRRUS",
                    "payerId": "06111",
                    "payerName": "Oxford Health Plans, Inc.",
                    "kafkaWorkflow": "COMPLETED",
                    "providerRequestReason": "Paper or Electronic Check",
                    "resubmissionCount": "0",
                    "assignedTopic": "STOP",
                    "cu_ticketSubmittedDate_date": "2022-05-30 10:00:49",
                    "cu_ticketLastUpdated_date": "2022-05-30 10:01:27.015",
                    "cu_ticketNumber": "PIQ-9845631",
                    "cu_totalAttachments_int": 0,
                    "cu_resubmission_count_int": 0,
                    "cu_bizAge_int": 1,
                    "bookOfBusinessTypeCd": "OX",
                    "actualClaimNumber": "DC29723201",
                    "coverageType": "M",
                    "remarkCodes": "PPO008,COVD01",
                    "smbInd": "F",
                    "advocateCreatedOn": "2022-05-30",
                    "ticketResubmissions": [
                        {
                            "openDate": "2022-05-30"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ticketComments": [
                        {
                            "comment": "test",
                            "category": "External",
                            "createdBy": "Shrutika Kadam",
                            "createDate": "2022-05-30",
                            "reconRequestReason": "Paper or Electronic Check"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "piqreporting",
                "_type": "ticketData",
                "_id": "9845638",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "claimNumber": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "adjustmentNumber": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "claimICN": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "claimStatus": "A",
                    "claimType": "I",
                    "claimFirstDateService": "2022-01-03",
                    "claimLastDateService": "2022-01-03",
                    "isBehaviourHealth": "false",
                    "claimPatientAccountNumber": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "claimBillingAmount": "393.77",
                    "claimPaidAmount": "292.61",
                    "claimCAE": "FACETS - CSP",
                    "subscriberId": "122220435",
                    "memberId": "122220435",
                    "subscriberFirstName": "CHARLES",
                    "subscriberLastName": "TAYLOR",
                    "subscriberDateOfBirth": "1997-01-30",
                    "subscriberAddress": "15025 OAKS ROAD ",
                    "patientFirstName": "CHARLES",
                    "patientLastName": "TAYLOR",
                    "patientMiddleName": "G",
                    "patientDateOfBirth": "1997-01-30",
                    "govProgramCode": "0",
                    "coverageStartDate": "2022-01-01",
                    "coverageEndDate": "9999-12-31",
                    "groupNumber": "EXSG",
                    "relationshipCode": "EE",
                    "sourceId": "MDONEX  12222043501",
                    "billingMpin": "001131959",
                    "billingProviderName": "Murphy Medical Center",
                    "renderingMpin": "001131959",
                    "ticketNumber": "9845638",
                    "tpsmCode": "F",
                    "ticketTpsmIndicator": "99Z",
                    "ticketTpsmDescription": "DEFAULT VALUE",
                    "ticketSubmissionDate": "2022-05-30",
                    "ticketSubmitterName": "Lavanya Kadiala",
                    "ticketType": "Recon",
                    "ticketQueue": "Facets  CSP",
                    "providerTin": "520445374",
                    "policyNumber": "MDONEX",
                    "ticketStatus": "Under Review",
                    "ticketSubmitterEmail": "XXXXXXXXX",
                    "ticketSubmitterPhone": "8748468777",
                    "amountOwnedFlag": "Y",
                    "ticketLastUpdated": "2022-05-30",
                    "ticketLastUpdatedBy": "System",
                    "claimSubmissionTransactionId": "N/A",
                    "sourceApplication": "SDE",
                    "serviceProviderLastName": "Civista Medical Center",
                    "productId": "BVSCMD08",
                    "depedentSequenceNumber": "01",
                    "stateOfIssue": "MD",
                    "subscriberAddressLine1": "15025 OAKS ROAD",
                    "subscriberCity": "CHARLOTTE HALL",
                    "subscriberState": "MD",
                    "subscriberZip5": "20622",
                    "billingType": "131",
                    "claimIndicator": "O",
                    "claimRecievedDate": "2022-01-18",
                    "ticketLastUpdatedName": "System",
                    "planBenefitTypeCode": "MD",
                    "claimNetworkStatus": "O",
                    "offshoreRestricted": "N",
                    "isEmployeeRestricted": "N",
                    "providerComments": "PIQ Integration testing smb data",
                    "platform": "FACETS - CSP",
                    "payerId": "87726",
                    "payerName": "UnitedHealthcare",
                    "kafkaWorkflow": "COMPLETED",
                    "providerRequestReason": "Paper or Electronic Check",
                    "resubmissionCount": "0",
                    "assignedTopic": "STOP",
                    "cu_ticketSubmittedDate_date": "2022-05-30 10:34:28",
                    "cu_ticketLastUpdated_date": "2022-05-30 10:35:55.868",
                    "cu_ticketNumber": "PIQ-9845638",
                    "cu_totalAttachments_int": 0,
                    "cu_resubmission_count_int": 0,
                    "cu_bizAge_int": 1,
                    "actualClaimNumber": "22A647807600",
                    "coverageType": "M",
                    "facetsprovIdBilling": "0421644502",
                    "facetsprovIdRendering": "0421644001",
                    "remarkCodes": "i61",
                    "smbInd": "S",
                    "smbProvStCd": "MD",
                    "advocateCreatedOn": "2022-05-30",
                    "ticketAdjustment": [
                        {
                            "adjustmentNumber": "SF20220530824490968",
                            "adjustmentSource": "FACETS - CSP",
                            "createdOn": "2022-05-30"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ticketResubmissions": [
                        {
                            "openDate": "2022-05-30"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ticketComments": [
                        {
                            "comment": "PIQ Integration testing smb data",
                            "category": "External",
                            "createdBy": "Lavanya Kadiala",
                            "createDate": "2022-05-30",
                            "reconRequestReason": "Paper or Electronic Check"
                        },
                        {
                            "comment": "Under Review",
                            "category": "Internal",
                            "createdBy": "System",
                            "ticketStatus": "Under Review",
                            "createDate": "2022-05-30",
                            "conclusion": "Under Review",
                            "reconRequestReason": "Paper or Electronic Check",
                            "createdById": "System"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to get the data from the elasticsearch by adding the filters like cu_ticketLastUpdated_date  and platform columns. To achieve this I am using the below c# code

```cs
public static string COSMOS(string getAPiurl, string ApiUserId, string ApiPassword)
{
    string url = getAPiurl;
    HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    webrequest.Method = "POST";
    webrequest.ContentType = "application/JSON";
    webrequest.Accept = "application/JSON";

    String username = ApiUserId;
    String password = ApiPassword;
    String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(username + ":" + password));

    webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webrequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{\"query\":{\"bool\":{\"should\":[{\"match\":{\"platform\":{\"query\":\"COSMOS\"}}}],\"filter\":[{\"range\":{\"cu_ticketLastUpdated_date\":{\"gte\":\"2022-05-01 00:00:00\",\"lt\":\"2022-05-31 23:59:59\"}}}]}}}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var rl = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        httpResponse.Close();
    }
}
```

I am unable to get the response from the API. Can anyone help me with a solution.

Comment: Could you share the error that you observe ? what is the result of the request ?

Comment: I am not getting the data as per my request. I need to fetch the data only belongs to the platform: COSMOS. But instead of that I am getting entire data from that API which includes all the platform departments.

Comment: So from my understanding both the `c#` example and the dsl query in postman do not work ? They both return multiple kind of platforms such as `CIRRUS` / `COSMOS` /  `Facet - CSP` ?

Comment: Which indicate the error not to be with the `c#` example but the request you send ?

Comment: You may want to add the mapping of your index. (maybe not all of it but just the fields relevant to the question). For example you response dump is nice ... but contains way to much information

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

Why don't you use the [official c# library](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/introduction.html) ?